# Upon button click, popup window to enter data?

Tags: android, eclipse, popup

I have a button and when I press it I want a smaller window to popup (To where you can still see the previous screen, like a box inside a box). Inside that smaller popup box I want to be able to have the user input several things and when they hit OK it closes the popup window and adds the data back.

How would I go about doing this? Would I create another activity or maybe a dialog box? I tried creating another activity but couldn't figure out how to scale the size to make it smaller.

```
 public void newUserInput(View view){

    }
```

is the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare popup window and popupView and the layout inflator.

```
private PopupWindow pw;
private View popupView;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
```

in the oncreate method inflate the layout you want to show as popup.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false);
```

and this will be your onclick method.

```
public void newUserInput(View view){
    pw.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
    pw.setContentView(popupView);

    // Use any one method - showAtLocation or showAsDropDown to show the popup  
    pw.showAtLocation(parent, gravity, x, y);
    pw.showAsDropDown(anchor, xoff, yoff)


}
```

Comment: Will I be able to have the user enter in information and send it back to the activity that launched it? I dont think the popup is technically a new activity so I should be able to right?

Comment: Definitely you can. The popup is not a new activity so you may access the data entered in the popup right away.

Comment: Could you go in a bit more detail? You said it creates a new activity but I don't see that anywhere in here. What about the layout it's pulling. I dont have that, would that be with the new activity?